# Align the last 2 items in middle css Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm working with css grid. I'm new to this. I have 5 elements and 6 columns. But how to arrange the last 2 columns in center? Here is the code

```css
.points {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="points">
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example**

[See this image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiiFf.jpg)

Comment: Do you have to do it using `display: grid?` There are other easier ways!

Comment: then it's not a grid what you want, flexbox, inline-block, etc are more appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use grids, this is a way :)

```css
.points {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr .5fr .5fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  
}

.point-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
.point-2 {
  grid-column: 2 /4 
}
.point-4 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  
}
.point-5 {
  grid-column: 3 / -1;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="points">
      <div class="point point-1">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="point point-2">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="point point-3">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="point point-4">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="point point-5">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the same in flex :)

```css
.points {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}
.point {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="points">
      <div class="point">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this without using Grid as follows:

```css
.points {
text-align: center;
}

.point {
display: inline-block;
background-color: green;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin:30px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="points">
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="images/experience-5.png" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought what OP meant was that on the 2nd line the elements are more centered and not sticking to the left side. I could be wrong though.

Edit: just saw that there's a pic on the bottom of his post and I was right

Comment: In this answer the elements should be centrally aligned, are they not?

Comment: Take a look by running the snippet

Comment: @THess Maybe this is what you need to do? As i said, they are centrally aligned

Comment: I did not change anything other than add colours and sizes so that you could understand....?

Comment: Wait, then why were all the elements in one row before?

Comment: This is because they were all small so they fit into 1 row. The idea of `inline-block` is that they will fit in 1 row until they no longer can, then they will drop and create a new row. To make it easier for you to see, I made the elements bigger so that they took up 2 rows. I didn't change the core of what we are trying to accomplish, just made things more visible for you.

Comment: Oooh, okay, now I get it, sorry about that.

Comment: On full screen the items are in one row, or even maybe 4-1 on some screen sizes. Maybe OP wants the split up always and the other solution posted here earlier with having to split up the divs was maybe correct

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best solution.

But you could make two grids, one of 3 and one of 5. Use empty divs to fill up the first and middle cell of the 5 cell grid.

```css
.points3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.points5 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

img {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px
 }
 
 h2, h3 {
 text-align:center
 }
```

```html
<div class="points3">
    <div class="point">
      <h2><img src="https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stack-overflow-logo-vector-download.jpg" alt=""></h2>
      <h3>Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="point">
      <h2><img src="https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stack-overflow-logo-vector-download.jpg" alt=""></h2>
      <h3>Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="point">
      <h2><img src="https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stack-overflow-logo-vector-download.jpg" alt=""></h2>
      <h3>Text</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="points5">
 <div class="spacer"></div>
 
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stack-overflow-logo-vector-download.jpg" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
 <div class="spacer"></div>
  
  <div class="point">
    <h2><img src="https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stack-overflow-logo-vector-download.jpg" alt=""></h2>
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```